# Compare two text inside elements

Tags: jquery

I have the following html markup:

```
<div class="container-1">
  <div class="start-date">October 19th 2022</div>
  <div class="date-sep">-</div>
  <div class="end-date">October 19th 2022</div>
</div>
```

The page is a list of events divided in several containers (.container-1, .container-2, ...). When the end date (.end-date) of the event is equal to the start-date (.start-date) I want to hide the end date.

What I got so far:

```
(function($) {

  $(".start-date").attr("id", "startDate");
  var samedate = $("#startDate").text();
  $(".end-date:contains(' +++ samedate +++ ')").addClass("hide-date");
})(jQuery);
```

CSS:

```
.hide-date { display: none; }
```

Comment: What happens when you execute the code?

Comment: You need to take it a bit slower and look at your code, here you are missing quotes `$(.container-1 #startDate)`. Here you are missing the ending `"` `$(".end-date:contains(' +++ samedate +++ ')`

Comment: Nothing happens, the end date remains on the page.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my question with the quotes. It was correct on my page though. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @CliffVandyck If you quotes are fixed then this is the problem `$(".end-date:contains(' +++ samedate +++ ')")` check my answer below to see the correct

Comment: So select both elements. Read the text of each. If they match hide the element. `if($('.start-date').text() === $(".end-date").text()) $(".end-date").hide();`

Comment: Why are you setting the id to select the element again by that id?

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment you had multiple quotes missing from your code, it needs to look like this:

```
$(".start-date").attr("id", "startDate");
var samedate = $('.container-1 #startDate').text();
$(".end-date:contains(" + samedate + ")").addClass("hide-date");
```

Also I'm not sure if there is a specific reason why you use this line `$(".start-date").attr("id", "startDate")`. If it's only so you can use the select on the next line, then you dont need it.

**Demo**

```js
(function($) {

  $(".start-date").attr("id", "startDate");
  var samedate = $('.container-1 #startDate').text();
  $(".end-date:contains(" + samedate + ")").addClass("hide-date");
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.hide-date {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-1">
  <div class="start-date">October 19th 2022</div>
  <div class="date-sep">-</div>
  <div class="end-date">October 19th 2022</div>
</div>
```